# Datepicker for each input element in dynamically created rows?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-templates

I have a dynamic for loop as shown below. It creates rows with 4 columns. I wanted to add a datepicker for one of the column with input field().

```
 for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}

        <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
    <td class="docDate"><span><input type="text" id="idDocDate" class="clsDocDate" /><img src="../Images/Calendar.png" alt="" onclick="txtDatePicker(this);"/></span></td>

    </tr>
    {% } %}
```

I tried below code using "onclick" event on image button, but this does not work as expected. It shows the datepicker for each row, but the problem is it assigns the selected date value only to the first row. It doesn't matter which row i select, it still assigns to the first row only. Is there any workaround for this to get separate datepicker for eachrow??

```
function txtDatePicker(argDate) {
    var ele = $(argDate).closest('td').find('.clsDocDate');
    $(ele).datepicker({
        showOn: 'button'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is because you have duplicate id's for the date input field, remove the id attribute from the date field

```
<input type="text" class="clsDocDate" />
```

Demo: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M4x5k/), [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M4x5k/2/)

Comment: Is there anyway I could get that datepicker as soon as I click on my image icon??